# {R grid}: how to create a polygon half filled with color?

Tags: r, graphics, geometry, polygon, r-grid

(This question might be too difficult, and maybe not worth the hassle to solve - however, if there is an easy solution - I would be curious to know)

Let's say I create an image (using the grid package) which looks like this:

```
require(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.polygon(x=c((0:4)/10, rep(.5, 5), (10:6)/10, rep(.5, 5)),
             y=c(rep(.5, 5), (10:6/10), rep(.5, 5), (0:4)/10),
             id=rep(1:5, 4),
             gp=gpar(fill=1:5))
```

But now, what if I wish to have some of the polygons only partially filled (let's say one will be 1/3 filled and another 1/2 filled and the other fully filled with color)  So it would look like partially filled glass of water.

I imagine it can be done when constructing the polygons, the question is, assuming I want something to calculate the new polygons only based on the proportions I give it - how can that be done.

The motivation for my question comes from wanting to present another layer of information on logo plots (see the function seqLogo in the package seqLogo)

Thanks.

Comment: I guarantee that no normal person will be able to read such an information effectively (think of comparing if 40% filled C is more filled than 35% filled A); the better idea is to try with colors.

Comment: Thanks mbq, the problem is that it already has to use 4 colors (one for each codon letter).  So using different coloring would probably totally mess the image as well.

Comment: @Tal Galili: @mbq has a very good point as it would be extremely difficult to compare the various percentages as different squares have different areas, so 20% of the outer square may be bigger than 30% of the inner one. What about using the transparency of the color instead? Also, why don't you use the same size for each square? I don't see how this would improve logo plots, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi Nico, the square example is not the one for the logo plot.  To give the logo plot example the code would need to be longer, and include more packages (I tried to have my example minimal).  It does reflect the logo plot problem in that in it there are different sizes to the letters.  Either way I understand both your points regarding the Interpretability of the graph - back to the drawing board I guess :)

Comment: @Tal: But each letter has other shape, so you don't need to use different colors for them. On the other hand, as nico suggested, you can use saturation of color, not hue.

For others, here is an example of a logo plot: http://weblogo.berkeley.edu/img/cap_dna.png

Comment: mbq - good point about the colors - I was too fixed into thinking how to preserve the original format.  I might play with that instead - thank you :)

Comment: In general, it's a poor decision to use only one form of information to present any aspect of your data.  Try to approach each aspect of your data in multiple ways.  For instance, use a color + a label, or use luminosity + a pattern.  Otherwise, you run the risk of leaving your audience hanging if they can't process something.  Red/green color-blindness and prior exposure to shape cues are often insurmountable barriers between your graphic and your audience if used as the only cue for a specific aspect of a datum.  My advice?  Be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can partially fill a polygon by drawing it twice: first draw the whole thing with an outline but no fill, then draw the filling.  You can see this more easily with a simple rectangle example.

```
x <- c(left = 0.25, right = 0.75)
y <- c(bottom = 0.1, mid = 0.6, top = 0.9)

grid.newpage()
grid.polygon(x =  rep(x[c("left", "right", "right", "left")], 2),
             y =  y[rep(c("bottom", "top", "bottom", "mid"), each = 2)],
             id = rep(1:2, each = 4),
             gp = gpar(fill = c(NA, "blue")))
```

Comment: This is the same approach I would recommend, but I have one improvement to suggest: draw the fill *first* and then the outline.  Otherwise, you can get some weird pixel-overlap issues in the actual implementation, especially with smaller shapes.